# How do I download Bootstrap's growl?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-notify

Guys I've been trying to download this plugin for bootstrap. It's called [Growl](http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/). The link doesn't give the instruction how to download it. Also I tried running the code without the plugin because maybe this is already built-in in the bootstrap but no. It isn't. There are other `Growl` plugins too but I like this one.

Comment: You could use nuget command line PM> Install-Package Growl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on the GitHub icon on the plugin's page which will take you to their [GitHub page](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-growl). There you can download it from dist folder.

Comment: Oh my God, I didn't know it was a Github icon, I'm not familiar with Github's icon. I thought it was some sort of a social networking site. Nonetheless thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah this was a terrible design flaw and well be fixed in the newest release at the end of January 2015